# Passing a string inline to a subroutine call, where the parameter has defined length, gives unexpected results

Tags: fortran, fortran95

I found this code to behave unexpectedly

```
module testmodule
   integer, parameter :: LCHARS = 50
contains
   subroutine init()
      call foobar("foobar")
   end subroutine

   subroutine foobar(s)
      character(len=*), intent(in) :: s
      call bar(s)
   end subroutine

   subroutine bar(str)
      character(len=LCHARS), intent(in)  :: str

      print *, str
   end subroutine
end module

program foo
   use testmodule
   call init()
end program
```

This code prints garbage which is compiler dependent.

I see the problem being the fact that I am jumping through a routine with `len=*` for a string argument, which is then passed to a routine with specified length for the string argument.

What's going on exactly under the hood, and where in the standard is this behavior described? Should I refrain from having specified length for character routine arguments, since this behavior may happen at any time without warning?

Answer (score 5):

I think your code is non-conforming. Section `12.4.1.1` of the Fortran 95 standard states:

> **12.4.1.1 Actual arguments associated with dummy data objects**
>   [...]
>   If a scalar dummy argument is of type default character, the length *len* of the dummy argument
>   shall be less than or equal to the length of the actual argument. The dummy argument becomes
>   associated with the leftmost *len* characters of the actual argument.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `bar` requires a string of length 50 (cf. `character(len=LCHARS), intent(in)  :: str`), whereas the string you are passing it is only of length 6. Compiling this with

> ifort -Warn all,nodec,interfaces,declarations -gen_interfaces -check all -std test.f90

produces the error

> forrtl: severe (408): fort: (18): Dummy character variable 'STR' has length 50 which is greater then actual variable length 6

As far as know **all Fortran arguments are passed by reference**. Behind the scenes, what the function `bar` gets is a pointer to the start of the string `str` and an extra parameter whose value is the length of the string. So `bar` will take 50 characters worth of memory, starting at the beginning of `str`, and print that to screen. Since the string that you pass is only 6 characters long, the remaining 44 characters will be whatever is in the next bit of memory after "foobar", which will differ at run time or depending on the compiler you use.

Comment: You were faster. More or less it is true, but Fortran arguments don't have to be passed by reference, although for strings and arrays it is very probable.

Comment: @VladimirF I presume that the Fortran standard doesn't specify how arguments are passed and this is left as an implementation detail. However, I assume that for strings and arrays thinking they are passed by reference won't get you into much trouble. Feel free to edit my answer if you can clarify this a bit.

Comment: It shouldn't get you much trouble at all, if you do not do things as linking with C or use attribute VALUE (obviously). I thing your answer is quite OK. For more http://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2009/07/10/doctor-fortran-in-ive-come-here-for-an-argument-side-2/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+IntelSoftwareNetworkBlog+%28Intel+Software+Network+Blog%29

Answer (score 2):

Argument passing is compiler-dependent, as long as the requirements of the standard are fulfilled, but generally, a CHARACTER(len=*) dummy argument will have an interface something like

void foo(char *s, int len)

and in the implementation of the foo procedure the hidden len argument is used as the string length. OTOH, for a CHARACTER(len=somevalue) argument the hidden len argument is either ignored or not passed at all, and the code for the procedure assumes that somevalue is the correct length of the string.

As you have seen, you should never use anything but LEN=* unless you really know what you're doing and can quote chapter and verse from the standard to explain why.

Comment: wouldn't it be better to forbid giving a specified length at all ? the assumption about the length is not guaranteed at all, because the code does not necessarily know the length of the string it is provided, and the compiler cannot always catch the error.

Comment: @StefanoBorini: The reason is historical. Back in the days of the dinosaurs, LEN=* did not exist. But when it got added, the old way still had to be retained in order to not break existing code.